# rest api post method not allowed

Tags: java, post

I am new with Rest api...I tried to build a realy simple rest api app and my GET method works well but POST method isn't!

I'm coding Java in Eclipse, using Tomcat 8.0 as my server.
I added all the jersey jars.

I have read all the suggested solutions here but nothing looks like my code.
So here is it:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)


@Path("{data}")
public static String main( @PathParam("data") String data)
{ 
    return "Hello "+data;
}
```

What is printing to the page "Hello abc" if i typed the url:

http://localhost:8081/REST_API/example/abc

But i don't know why when i do it with POST as i saw in some tutorial, it says:

**HTTP Error 405 Method not allowed.**

My POST code looks like:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)

@Path("{data}")

public String a()
{
    return "great post!!";
}
```

I think that the xml file is not the problem, because the GET methods works well.
Anyway, the xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>REST_API</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>     
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>example</param-value>    
    </init-param>     

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>   
 </servlet>  

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>  
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
 </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

While "example" is the name of the package.

I have seen all the youtube guides for "java rest api post", and as i said, i have seen here similar cases but their solutions are not good for me.

Please advice! Thanks!

Comment: How did you hit the end-point using POST?

Comment: Code looks perfectly ok to me. Looks like issue with the way you are hitting the server. To hit server with POST, you need to use either Browser apps like POSTMAN or Advanced REST Client. Or you can use Curl cmd tool

Comment: What client are you using, and did you specify the content type correctly in the header?

Comment: Sorry but i'm not sure i understood. for GET method all i need is eclipse (java code+xml that the servlet is in), tomcat server, and a browser. Am i must something else for POST? Can you attach a good tutorial for it please?